# How to match that using a JavaScript regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, match

This is my code:

```
var name = 'somename';
var pass = '123somen456';
var regex = new RegExp('.*' + pass + '.*', 'i');

alert(name.match(regex));
```

The regex just wont match, what I dont understand. Whats wrong here? I want to have a match as soon as any part of name is contained in pass, as long as that match is at least 4 chars long. Example:

som --> no match
some --> match

Thanks!

Comment: Please explain in English what you want to do, with example inputs and desired outputs.

Comment: I want to match "123somen456" on "somename". So if any part of "somename" is contained in 123somen456", it should match. Or said another way: If any part of pass is contained in name or the other way round, it should match.

Comment: So just one letter is enough? Also, please edit your question to clarify that.

Comment: Why shouldn't `som` match? It is contained in `123somen456`

Answer (score 0):

This regex requires that there are any amount of any character, then `123somen456`, and then any amount of any character. `name.match(regex)` will not return anything because `name` does not contain the string `123somen456`.

To test regular expressions, I recommend using http://regexpal.com/.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds, you may need to apply some algorithms like [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith-Waterman_algorithm) or [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BLAST).

If it is possible using regex in javascript, I'm interested to know.

*sorry buddy, I have no option to comment.*